# Webpage reloading on submitting form

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to make a web chat application using Node.js and Socket.io. I have the user typing into a input form and then click a send button to send a message. Right now it's in a development stage, so I just want to see if the message gets passed from the client to the server or not. So on my client-side, when the submit button is clicked, I use emit an event, and pass a message to the server. On my server-side, I have code that listens for this event and logs it out. But every time I run it, the client disconnects and re-connects every time the form is submitted, and the message isn't getting logged as I expected.

Here's the code from app.js

```
  io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('Client connected!');

  socket.on('message_sent', function(msg){// Just for testing purposes
    console.log('Clent says: ' + msg);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('Clent disconnected!');
  });
});
```

All I ever get is "Client connected!" and "Client Disconnected!" whenever I try to send a message.
And here's the script running on the client

```
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('message_sent', $('#usermessage').val());
    $('#usermessage').val('');
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

A proper explanation as to why this isn't working would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Could you show your html code as well? It looks like you are trying to follow this tutorial http://socket.io/get-started/chat/, I would make sure all of it matches.

Comment: @Noah yeah that's the one I was learning from. The code is pretty much the same except that I changed the front-end a little. Here's the code anyway: https://jsfiddle.net/o0kcb6xj/1/

Comment: can u switch to import jquery.js first before bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you place your script within `<head>` tag, before DOM manipulation you should make sure that the dom is ready because without that there is no `form` to attach a `submit` event to it; so wrap your script whithin jquery dom ready function:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      socket.emit('message_sent', $('#usermessage').val());
      $('#usermessage').val('');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Actually I shifted the client-side script all the way after the <body> and everything works fine now!

Comment: Of course you could place them there or if you place them on `<head>` tag you should call them on dom ready.

Answer (score 0):

HTML elements may have default settings applied to them that you could need to override. When you add a `<button/>` to a `<form/>` element, there is an event to be expected; the submission event. This is expecting to redirect to a specified url in the form. If the form has no url, it will reload the page. To override this, you'll need to prevent the default behavior of the button. Try this:

```
var socket = io();
$('form').submit(function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault(); //the secret sauce
  socket.emit('message_sent', $('#usermessage').val());
  $('#usermessage').val('');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Still not working! It's doing the exact same thing as before

Answer (score 0):

On the jsfiddle your form is just `<form>` try changing to `<form action="">` like in the tutorial you are using.

Comment: No luck yet. Still the same!

Comment: I would try doing it exactly as in the tutorial and then if that works you can start converting it to your version to narrow down the problem.