# Webpage with a simple form reloads on form submission

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML form and am using JavaScript to display the entered value to the webpage, but everytime I hit submit the webpage reloads.

I have read the question at [Webpage reloading on submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054487/webpage-reloading-on-submitting-form) but that is jQuery and `e.preventDefault();` isn't working in my case.
How to stop the page from reloading?

I have the following code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var pm1, sqrtInt, pm2, constInt;

  pm1 = document.getElementById("pm1").value;
  pm1 = document.getElementById("sqrtInt").value;
  pm1 = document.getElementById("pm2").value;
  pm1 = document.getElementById("constInt").value;

  document.getElementById("proof").innerHTML = 
      '<br>pm1 = ' + pm1 + 
      '<br>sqrtInt = ' + sqrtInt + 
      '<br>pm2 = ' + pm2 + 
      '<br>constInt = ' + constInt;
}
```

```css
#proof {
  background: black;
  color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div>Form Trial</div>
<div>
  <form onsubmit="myFunction()">
    <div>
      <select class="uk-select" id="pm1">
        <option>Minus (-)</option>
        <option>Plus (+)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="uk-input" type="text" placeholder="Square Root" id='sqrtInt'>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select id="pm2">
        <option>Minus (-)</option>
        <option>Plus (+)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Constant" id='constInt'>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value='submit'>
    </div>
  </form>
</div><br><br>
<div id="proof"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to do:

1. Add `return` to the `onsubmit` code:

   ```
   <form onsubmit="return myFunction()">
   ```
2. Add at the end of your `myFunction` function:

   ```
   return false;
   ```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var pm1, sqrtInt, pm2, constInt;

  pm1 = document.getElementById("pm1").value;
  pm1 = document.getElementById("sqrtInt").value;
  pm1 = document.getElementById("pm2").value;
  pm1 = document.getElementById("constInt").value;

  document.getElementById("proof").innerHTML = 
      '<br>pm1 = ' + pm1 + 
      '<br>sqrtInt = ' + sqrtInt + 
      '<br>pm2 = ' + pm2 + 
      '<br>constInt = ' + constInt;
  return false; // <---------
}
```

```css
#proof {
  background: black;
  color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div>Form Trial</div>
<div>
  <form onsubmit="return myFunction()">
    <div>
      <select class="uk-select" id="pm1">
        <option>Minus (-)</option>
        <option>Plus (+)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="uk-input" type="text" placeholder="Square Root" id='sqrtInt'>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select id="pm2">
        <option>Minus (-)</option>
        <option>Plus (+)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Constant" id='constInt'>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value='submit'>
    </div>
  </form>
</div><br><br>
<div id="proof"></div>
```